# How to locate app server folders from ibatis query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2012, mybatis, ibatis

I want to read app server folders from ibatis query.
I want to do a `BULK INSERT in SQL SERVER` for that I am framing one query Iin iBatis which has app server folder location (eg: `opt\sasu\import\abc.import`)These files are present in app server.
How can I write a query in ibatis. Below is the query which i wrote

```
BULK INSERT TABLENAME FROM ${importFilePath}
        WITH (            
              FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
              FORMATFILE =  ${formatFilePath}
             );
```

`importFilePath` and `formatFilePath` are the app server file location paths.
This query is expecting this files should present in database server.
Is thier any one to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem is solved by creating some network shared folder which is accessible from both app server and database server. The path of the folder as it is seen by database server is a configuration parameter (store it wherever you store other parameters in you application). The only important thing is that application server should know this path so it can construct correct query.

Usually you have some `ImportService` which responsibility is to import data.
It should get file and move or copy file to that shared folder and then invoke mapper.

```
public void import() {
    copyFileToSharedFolderAccessibleByDatabaseServer();
    mapper.importData();
}
```

Before calling mapper method this service should get this configuration parameter and construct correct path and pass it to mapper.
In your query either pass full path or path to folder and file name(s) like this:

```
interface MyMapper {
   void importData(@Param("importFilesFolder") String importFileFolder,
                   @Param("importFile") String importFile,
                   @Param("formatFile") String formatFile);
}
```

In MyMapper.xml:

```
BULK INSERT TABLENAME FROM ${imporFilesFolder}\${importFile}
    WITH (            
          FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
          FORMATFILE =  ${imporFilesFolder}\${formatFile}
         );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as we don't have permissions to access the share folder in app server , we shifted to other solution which is nothing but bcp.We installed some microft clinet and utility softwares on client machine and passed the required parameters through ProcessBuilder java class.It works fine.